Kafka CRC calculation
I´m trying to generate a kafka producer message by native tcpip on .net, I have the message already done, but I´m missing something on CRC calculation, I generate a CRC calculation with:
  public class CRC32C
{
    private const uint POLY = 0x1EDC6F41;
    private static readonly uint[,] crc32cTable = new uint[8, 256];

    // Function to initialize the CRC32C table
    public void InitCRC32C()
    {
        uint n, crc, k;

        // Initialize the CRC32C table
        for (n = 0; n < 256; n++)
        {
            crc = n;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                crc = (crc & 1) != 0 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
            }
            crc32cTable[0, n] = crc;
        }

        for (n = 0; n < 256; n++)
        {
            crc = crc32cTable[0, n];
            for (k = 1; k < 8; k++)
            {
                crc = crc32cTable[0, crc & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
                crc32cTable[k, n] = crc;
            }
        }
    }

    // Software CRC32C calculation
    public uint CRC32Ccalculate(uint crc, byte[] buffer, int length)
    {
        uint crcVal = crc ^ 0xffffffff;
        int index = 0;

        // Process any leading bytes to bring the data pointer to an eight-byte boundary
        while (length > 0 && (index & 7) != 0)
        {
            crcVal = crc32cTable[0, (crcVal ^ buffer[index]) & 0xff] ^ (crcVal >> 8);
            index++;
            length--;
        }

        // Process 8-byte aligned blocks
        while (length >= 8)
        {
            ulong ncopy = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, index);
            crcVal ^= (uint)ncopy; // Assume the buffer is little-endian
            crcVal = crc32cTable[7, crcVal & 0xff] ^
                     crc32cTable[6, (crcVal >> 8) & 0xff] ^
                     crc32cTable[5, (crcVal >> 16) & 0xff] ^
                     crc32cTable[4, (crcVal >> 24) & 0xff] ^
                     crc32cTable[3, (crcVal >> 32) & 0xff] ^
                     crc32cTable[2, (crcVal >> 40) & 0xff] ^
                     crc32cTable[1, (crcVal >> 48) & 0xff] ^
                     crc32cTable[0, crcVal >> 56];
            index += 8;
            length -= 8;
        }

        // Process remaining bytes
        while (length > 0)
        {
            crcVal = crc32cTable[0, (crcVal ^ buffer[index]) & 0xff] ^ (crcVal >> 8);
            index++;
            length--;
        }

        return crcVal ^ 0xffffffff;
    }


}

Here it´s correct message from Python producer:

0000008d000000070000000300176b61666b612d707974686f6e2d70726f64756365722d32ffff0001000075300000000100086d792d746f70696300000001000000000000004a00000000000000000000003e00000000021d161b720000000000000000019401ee89d10000019401ee89d1ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff000000011800000006666f6f0662617200
where 1d161b72 its the ACK.
I tried to make calculation, but I cannot reach this value.
Seems i should take the values from CRC in advance to the end of message, but not get same result. I suppose Algorithm it´s not correct, but i´m not sure about it.
So when I try to generate the message by my self, I get error on the kafka response as -2 error, mean CRC calculation error. Any help on this?
My target it's implement Kafka producer over microcontroller protocol, but I would like to test before on .net


First off, how do you know that the error is due to the CRC? Second, the screen shot is of no use whatsoever. What we'd need to be able to help is an example of at least one correct message with its CRC, in hexadecimal, identifying the CRC and the portion of the message that the CRC is calculated over.

Also, your code is missing POLY.

Thanks Mark, you were right, i edited. Thanks for your help @MarkAdler

Your correct message example has a message size of 62, but you are only providing the first 53 bytes in your hex dump. You need to provide the whole thing.
